# Is it possible to create a forged file which has the same checksums using two different algorithms?

Tags: security, cryptography

I was a bit inspired by this blog entry http://blogs.technet.com/dmelanchthon/archive/2009/07/23/windows-7-rtm.aspx (German)

The current notion is that md5 and sha1 are both somewhat broken. Not easily and fast, but at least for md5 in the range of a practical possibility.  (I'm not at all a crypto expert, so maybe I'm wrong in stuff like that).

So I asked myself if it would be possible to create a file A' which has the **same size**, the **same md5 sum**, and the **same sha1 sum** as the original file A.

First, would it be possible at all?

Second, would it be possible in reality, with current hardware/software?

If not, wouldn't be the easiest way to provide assurance of the integrity of a file to use always two different algorithms, even if they have some kind of weakness?

**Updated**:

Just to clarify: the idea is to have a file A and a file A' which fullfills the conditions:

```
size(A) == size(A') && md5sum(A) == md5sum(A') && sha1sum(A) == sha1sum(A')
```

Comment: This is actualy an interesting idea, similar to the original reasoning behind DES3. `md5` is somewhat broken, `sha1` is somewhat broken, the probability of finding a joint collision would be `P(md5sum(A) == md5sum(A')) * P(sha1sum(A) == sha1sum(A'))` as they are mutualy independent, wich means, really small. But for file sharing, I guess it's too much work for a too much of a small gain, as you can redownload the file from the official source. For a fast check `md5` is good enough.

Comment: Alas, the two algorithms are from the same family, and hence not independent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Would it be possible at all?" - yes, if the total size of the checksums is smaller than the total size of the file, it is impossible to avoid collisions.

"would it be possible in reality, with current hardware/software?" - if it is feasible to construct a text to match a given checksum for each of the checksums in use, then yes.

See [wikipedia on concatenation of cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Concatenation_of_cryptographic_hash_functions), which is also a useful term to google for.

From that page:

> "However, for Merkle-Damgård hash
>   functions, the concatenated function
>   is only as strong as the best
>   component, not stronger. Joux noted
>   that 2-collisions lead to
>   n-collisions: if it is feasible to
>   find two messages with the same MD5
>   hash, it is effectively no more
>   difficult to find as many messages as
>   the attacker desires with identical
>   MD5 hashes. Among the n messages with
>   the same MD5 hash, there is likely to
>   be a collision in SHA-1. The
>   additional work needed to find the
>   SHA-1 collision (beyond the
>   exponential birthday search) is
>   polynomial. This argument is
>   summarized by Finney."

Comment: I wouldn't have searched for the term concatenation in this context, but I guess that is the answer to my question.

That leaves only the question for the probability to do something like this in reality.

Comment: That latter question is answered by moonshadow too, in the quote: Using the two together is not substantially harder than using the best of the two on its own.

Answer (score 0):

For a naive answer, we'd have make some (incorrect) assumptions:

- Both the SHA1 and MD5 hashing algorithms result in an even distribution of hash values for a set of random inputs
- Algorithm details aside--a random input string has an equally likely chance of producing any hash value

(Basically, no clumping and nicely distributed domains.)

If the probability of discovering a string that collides with another's SHA1 hash is p1, and similarly p2 for MD5, the naive answer is the probability of finding one that collides with both is p1*p2.

However, the hashes are both broken, so we know our assumptions are wrong.

The hashes have clumping, are more sensitive to changes with some data than others, and in other words, aren't perfect.  On the other hand, a perfect, non-broken hashing algorithm will have the above properties, and that's exactly what makes it hard to find collisions.  They're random.

The probability intrinsically depends on the properties of the algorithm--basically, since our assumptions aren't valid, we can't "easily" determine how hard it is.  In fact, the difficultly of finding input that collides likely depends very strongly on the characteristics of the input string itself.  Some may be relatively easy (but still probably impractical on today's hardware), and due to the different nature of the two algorithms, some may actually be impossible.

Answer (score -1):

> So I asked myself if it would be
>   possible to create a file A' which has
>   the same size, the same md5 sum, and
>   the same sha1 sum as the original file
>   A.

Yes, make a copy of the file.

Other than that, not without large amounts of computing resources to check tons of permutations (assuming the file size is non-trivial).

You can think of it like this:

If file size increases by n, the likelihood of a possible fake increases, but the computing costs necessary to test the combinations increases exponentially by 2^n.

So the bigger your file is, the more likely there *is* a dupe out there, but the less likely you are at finding it.

Comment: -1 for sounding authoritative without actually being a cryptographer (see moonshadow's answer for the _correct_ assessment of the security of the two concatenated)

Comment: @Nick: I fully agree. In crypto there are quite a number of surprising and unintuitive results. Concatenation of hashes is one of them and just plain guessing doesn't work here.

Answer (score -1):

In theory yes you can have it, in practice it's hell of a collusion. In practice no one even able to create a SHA1 collusion let alone MD5 + SHA1 + Size at the same time. This combination is simply impossible right now without having the whole computer power in the world and run it for a while.

Although in the close future we might see more vulnerabilities in SHA1 and MD5. And with the support of better hardware (especially GPU) why not.

Answer (score -2):

In theory you could do this. In practice, if you started from the two checksums provided by MD5 and SHA1 and tried to create a file that produced the same two checksums - it would be very difficult (many times more difficult than creating a file that produced the same MD5 checksum, or SHA1 checksum in isolation).